# Retrieving memory address with multiple nested struct pointers

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I have a (hopefully) very simple issue that has been giving me problems for a while now. Given these structs

```
typedef struct
{
    void * entity;
} link_t;

typedef struct
{
    link_t * current;
} list_t;
```

and a function prototype

```
void *list_get_entity(list_t *list);
```

I need the function list_get_entity to return the address of the data that "entity" is pointing to. The best I've been able to do so far is

```
void *list_get_entity(list_t *list)
{
     return list->current->entity;
}
```

which at least compiles and runs, but gives me gibberish. If for some reason the full file is needed to figure something out please let me know, although I'm sure there's other bugs in there I have yet to find because of this error.

Edit: fixed the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the address of the data `entity` is pointing to just return it directly

```
return list->current->entity;
```

The `void*` is an address hence returning it directly by value will give the caller the address of the data

Comment: From what I can tell this fixed the problem, and I feel pretty silly now. Now I get to go track down my other (likely malloc related) errors. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

```
typedef struct
{
   void * entity;
} link_t;

typedef struct
{
   link_t * current;
} list_t;

void * list_get_entity(list_t *list)
{
  return list->current->entity;
}
```

`list->current` is a pointer to `link_t`; `list->current->entity` is a pointer to entity type.
If you add &() around `list->current->entity`, it becomes pointer to pointer to `void`.